# Jahn-Teller effect is based on the Born-Oppenheimer approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, quantum-chemistry

I am now reading the quantum mechanics textbook by Landau and Lifshitz.

In section 102, they discuss the [Jahn-Teller effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect).

It seems that they assume the [Born-Oppenheimer approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation). There is no dynamics for the nuclei. Their positions are simply parameters for the electrons.

This then means a pitfall. The finiteness of the masses of the nuclei means the nuclei have dynamics and can tunnel between Born-Oppenheimer potential minima. This then means the symmetry of the nuclei configuration is restored.

Is this understanding right?

Comment: Chapter 100 says in its first paragraph "We usually discuss the configuration corresponding to the equilibrium position of the nuclei". Surely this can't be a talk about full Hamiltonian of electrons and nuclei, so at least Born-Oppenheimer approximation is in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this understanding is correct. The Born-Oppenheimer is assumed in the derivation of the Jahn-Teller effect.

Also, the scenario you describe in the last paragraph is qualitatively similar to the Dynamic Jahn-Teller effect.

Comment: It might be important to add here that the Jahn-Teller effect itself is actually a breakdown of the Born-Oppenheimer Approximation since it originates from an interaction between electronic and vibrational "motions".